# Applying changes made with xmodmap

Tags: keyboard, xmodmap

I'm trying to switch the Ctrl and Command keys using xmodmap, but even though the output of `xmodmap -pke` shows that the key codes were changed, the keys still perform the original function.

This is what I'm doing:

`xmodmap -e "keycode 37 = Super_L"`

`xmodmap -e "keycode 133 = Control_L"`

Is there any other step that I should take? I tried rebooting and adding the xmodmap call to `.xinitrc`, but it didn't work.

I'm running Ubuntu 14.04 on VirtualBox (the vbox "host key combination" is the Left Option key, so I don't think this is a problem).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to add the `clear` and `add` lines to make changes to the modifier keys.

This is what I'm using now:

```
clear control
clear mod4

keycode 37 = Super_L NoSymbol Super_L
keycode 133 = Control_L NoSymbol Control_L

add control = Control_L Control_R
add mod4 = Super_L Super_R
```

Just put those lines in a file called `.Xmodmap` and in your `.xinitrc`:

```
xmodmap $HOME/.Xmodmap
```

If you don't have a `.xinitrc` in your home dir, just create one.

Source: [this answer on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21989709/81108)